# Products per row Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

i have this Woocommerce site and i want to display 6 products per row. I try adding some code to functions.php and changing li width with css. Here is the website: codedoors.com/styleindia. Too i tried WooCommerce Product Archive Customizer plugin but not work.

My functions.php file:

```
// Display 24 products per page. //working
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 9;' ), 20 );


// Change number or products per row to 3 //not working
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 6; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made 6 products to display per row using the CSS style itself. I will provide you with the style how i have changed it.

**Stylesheet 1:**

Hide the line that i have mentioned below

http://codedoors.com/styleindia/wp-content/themes/smartshop/assets/css/smartshop-woocommerce.css?ver=1.0

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(4n+1) {
    /*clear: both !important;*/
}
```

And in the same file change the style of selector to this

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
  clear: none !important;
  margin: 2% !important;
  width: 12% !important; /* you have given here it as 15% */
}
```

And final one is to apply the style for the UL class .products and you can paste this anywhere you want but if is not been applied put it under important tag.

```
.products {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the screen shot that have made by applying the style that i have sent to you. http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1480013/f65662d652f36b254a9882ce4ba6011a

Hope this solution helps you.

Comment: I have problem right now on mobile devices. They appear broken. You have any idea?

Comment: Will check it up and post wait. Have you added any media query for displaying the style.

Comment: Here is the style that you have to use it for mobile version and i found that you have written some styles already and you have to change that in the same style sheet and add some code to that section itself. `@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    ul.products li.product{
        width:100% !important;
        float:left; /* Previous it was none */ 
    }
.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
  clear: none !important;
 /*margin: 2% !important;
 width: 12% !important;*/
}
}` Hope this style helps to rectify in mobile too.